# Find the minimum value dependent on columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My data looks like this

```
data = [['29/10/18', 'EDF', 'Online', 400, 500, 300], 
        ['29/10/18', 'EDF', 'Standard', 200, 100, 300], 
        ['29/10/18', 'NPower', 'Saver', 600, 500, 700],
        ['30/10/18', 'British Gas', 'Fixed Tariff', 300, 500, 600]] 


df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', 'Supplier', 'Product', 'Eastern Price', 'Southern Price', 'South West Price']) 

print(df)
```

I'm looking to find the cheapest price per day by region.

So output should look like

```
Date Region MinPrice
```

Can anyone help?

So far this is what I have but I'd like to have it for every region (theres about 15 in my dataset) and just have it set by date rather than every entry in my dataset

```
df.groupby(['date'])['date','Eastern Price'].transform('min')
```

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC need `melt` and then `groupby` to easily find all the region columns we can use `filter`

```
df1 = pd.melt(
    df,
    id_vars=["date"],
    value_vars=df.filter(like="Price"), # this finds the region columns.
    var_name="region",
    value_name="amount",
).groupby(["date", "region"]).agg(minPrice=('amount','min'))
```

---

```
print(df1)

                             minPrice
date       region                    
2018-10-29 Eastern Price          200
           South West Price       300
           Southern Price         100
2018-10-30 Eastern Price          300
           South West Price       600
           Southern Price         500
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do `stack` with `min`

```
df.set_index(['date', 'Supplier', 'Product']).stack().min(level=[0,3])
date                      
29/10/18  Eastern Price       200
          Southern Price      100
          South West Price    300
30/10/18  Eastern Price       300
          Southern Price      500
          South West Price    600
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Can you explain the use of `level=[0,3]`

Comment: @Sheldore you can think like groupby level 0 and 3 and aggregating `min` :)